# Kafka Streams GlobalKTable and accessing the record headers

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In the same way `KStream` and `KTable#toStream()` allow calling `process` or `transform` and thus enable inspecting the record headers, is there a way to achieve the same with `GlobalKTable`. Basically, I am looking for a way to inspect the record headers in the Kafka topic when consuming it as a `GlobalKTable`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, you could use `#addGlobalStore` instead?

Note thought, that the "global processor" should never modify the data but `put()` the key-value-pair (and maybe timestamp) unmodified into the `(Timestamped)KeyValue` store (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8037)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the ability to pass a processor the main difference between `#addGlobalStore` and `#globalTable`? Ultimately, the state stores created by both calls can be used for the same use case, right? such as querying the state store.

Comment: Yes, `globalTable` just calls `addGlobalStore` under the hood with a pre-defined `Processor`.